# Apply Filter to class property in Where

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created the following RangeFilter:

```
public class RangeFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : struct, IConvertible, IComparable {

  public T? Maximum { get; private set; }
  public T? Minimum { get; private set; }

  public RangeFilter(T? minimum, T? maximum) {
    Minimum = minimum;
    Maximum = maximum;
  }

  public Boolean Matches(T value) {

    if (Minimum != null && Maximum != null)
      return value.CompareTo(Minimum) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(Maximum) <= 0;
    if (Minimum == null && Maximum != null)
      return value.CompareTo(Maximum) <= 0;

    if (Minimum != null && Maximum == null)
      return value.CompareTo(Minimum) >= 0;

    return false;

  } // Matches

} // RangeFilter
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
RangeFilter<Int32> filter = new RangeFilter<Int32>(2, 4);

Boolean match = filter.Matches(2);
```

I need to integrate this as a Where extension:

```
public class Product {
  public Int32 Rating { get; set; }
}

List<Product> products = context.Products.Where(x => x.Rating, filter);
```

So I am applying the Filter to the value of x.Rating ...

I am doing it this way because I will have multiple Filter types all implementing IFilter and a few more things.

How can I create this extension?

Comment: why do you need this as an extension method instead of just using `filter` directly in the `Where` predicate? `context.Products.Where(x => filter.Matches(x.Rating))`

Comment: Because I will have multiple types of filter and inside the Where extension I will determine which type of filter it as according to a expression I will also pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class FilterExtensions
{
    public static bool Matches<T>(this T input, IFilter<T> filter) 
        where T : struct, IConvertible, IComparable
    {
        return filter.Matches(input);
    }
}

List<Product> products = context.Products.Where(x => x.Rating.Matches(filter));
```

which is identical to

```
List<Product> products = context.Products.Where(x => filter.Matches(x.Rating));
```

In your comment you added this:

> Because I will have multiple types of filter and inside the Where
>   extension I will determine which type of filter it as according to a
>   expression I will also pass.

I'm not sure if that warrants adding an extension, since in this case the extension seems redundant.

If you have an expression in your Linq query which is determining which filter to use, that query will likely be difficult to read. It could get extremely messy if you determine that you need to filter based on more than one property.

Based on that I'd recommend defining filters for the entire class, not just one property. You could have an `IFilter<T>` where `T` is `Product`, not a property of `Product`.

That enables you to write `ProductFilter` as a class that you can unit test. When you have one condition that class is really simple. If you have more conditions then you can modify `ProductFilter` and inject a collection of `Func<Product, bool>` and run each `Product` through the conditions.

I wouldn't recommend going into all out overkill right up front. But if you take logic like those filters and isolate them into separate classes then you accomplish a few things:

- You can unit test those filters
- If a method requires a filter you can mock it so that you can test your methods apart from the filters
- It will be easier to read.