# Exclude complex property with reflection get properties

Tags: c#

I want to read all public properties from a class with reflection except the Subject property because its a complex type/navigation property.

I want to exclude the Subject AND Pupils property in a generic working way.

Other property types like string is fine!

Is that somehow possible or do I have to "mark" that property with an ExludeColumnAttribute?

```
public class Schoolyear
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public List<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `typeof(Schoolyear).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name != "Subject")`

Comment: I refined my question pls see update!

Comment: What counts as a "complex" property?  `Pupils` could be considered just as complex as `Subject`.

Comment: @dbc `GetTypeCode` isn't a memer of `PropertyInfo` as far as I'm aware...

Comment: @dbc Do you mean this? `typeof(Schoolyear).GetProperties().Where(p => Type.GetTypeCode(p.PropertyType) != TypeCode.Object)`

Comment: Pupils inherits from IEnumerable, Subject not!

Comment: So exclude all classes, except those that implement `IEnumerable`?  Are there any other exceptions?

Comment: I think you're asking for the "base" types from the mscor library? If so, there isn't really an easy way to filter. One workaround is to check `is IConvertable` and `is IComparable` which the basic types all implement. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38512628/1462295

Comment: You can use [`Type.GetTypeCode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypecode(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if a property's returned type is complex or not, e.g. `typeof(Schoolyear).GetProperties().Where(p => Type.GetTypeCode(p.PropertyType) != TypeCode.Object)`.  But both `Subject` and `List<Pupil>` look complex to me so I don't understand how you would want to distinguish between them.  @BradleyUffner - I replaced my earlier comment with this corrected version.

Comment: Also, `String` is also `IEnumerable<char>` so you'll need to clarify on whether string is complex or not.

Comment: That line of code made my day: entity.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => Type.GetTypeCode(p.PropertyType) != TypeCode.Object); THANKS!

Comment: It's probably just going to be easier for you to mark them with an attribute.